# Extracting ZIP code from the address line

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, extract, fuzzy-comparison

I have a data frame which has address as one of the column, the address can sometimes contain ZIP/PIN code in it and sometimes not.

Data Frame:

```
BANK                        ADDRESS                                                    
ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK   REHMAT MANZIL, V. N. ROAD,CURCHGATE, MUMBAI - 400020     
VIJAYA BANK                 BOKARO CITY JHARKHAND,15/D1 HOTEL BLUE-,DIAMOND COMPLEX,BOKARO CITY,JHARKHAND,JHARKHAND
ALLAHABAD BANK              DANKIN GANJ DIST. MIRZAPUR - 231 001 UTTAR PRADESH
```

How can i extract only ZIP/PIN code with the following information:

```
 1. ZIP/PIN code are 6 digits (INDIAN ZIP/PIN CODE)
 2. ZIP are sometimes split by 3 digits, 560 015
 3. ZIP are sometimes separated by -, eg: 560-015
```

Below is my present code:

```
 df$zip <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$ADDRESS, "(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)")
```

But the above code does not account point 2 and 3 of my logic, that is handle the ZIP split by "" or "-"

Comment: `stri_match_last_regex` from `stringi` package should work.

Comment: @manju116 could you give me an example of how stri_match_last_regex be used here?

Comment: `lapply(c("REHMAT MANZIL, V. N. ROAD,CURCHGATE, MUMBAI - 400020", "DANKIN GANJ DIST. MIRZAPUR - 231 001 UTTAR PRADESH"),
        function(x) {
          paste(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]")), collapse="")
        })`

Comment: @SimonMüller how do we extract the pin code if the address is "40,REHMAT MANZIL, V. N. ROAD,CURCHGATE, MUMBAI - 400020" ?

Answer (score 0):

> But the above code does not account point 2 and 3 of my logic, that is
>   handle the ZIP split by "" or "-"

```
 m = regexpr("\\<\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{3}\\>", df$ADDRESS)
 df$zip = substr(df$ADDRESS, m, m + attr(m, "match.length") - 1)
```